# Terraform template_file failed to render

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to pass an array to my script file in terraform using **template_file**.

My terraform code is:

```
variable "services" {
   type = list(string)
   default = ["Service1", "Service2", "service3"]
}

variable "passwords" {
   type = list(string)
   default = ["Password1", "Password2", "Password3"]
}

data "template_file" "configure" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/init/configure")}"
  vars = {
    services  = join(",",var.services)
    passwords = join(",",var.passwords)

  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "grafana_nodes" {
  ...
  user_data = data.template_file.config
  ...
}
```

and this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a services_array
services_array=($(echo "${services}" | tr "," " "))

declare -a passwords_array
passwords_array=($(echo "${passwords}" | tr "," " "))

sudo echo "${services_array[@]}" >> /tmp/isp_services_array.txt
sudo echo "${passwords_array[@]}" >> /tmp/influx_db_passwords_array.txt
```

But when I try to run `terraform plan` I receive the error:

```
Error: failed to render : <template_file>:8,29-30: Invalid character; This character is not used within the language., and 2 other diagnostic(s)
│ 
│   with module.mymodule.data.template_file.configure,
│   on modules/mymodule/main.tf line 417, in data "template_file" "configure":
│  417: data "template_file" "configure" {
```

Could someone know how can use an array values in my script?
If I run the script internally (loggin to the ec2 instance) works fine.

Comment: If you want to persist the `$` you have to use two of those, i.e., `($$(echo "${services}" | tr "," " "))`.

Comment: Do you actually need the two files created?

Comment: What's the desired input for the user_data? I don't really see why you need `template_file` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the support.

I solved in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( j=1; j<${count_services}+1; j++ ));
do
  service=$(sudo echo "${services}" | cut -d ',' -f $j)
  password=$(sudo echo "${passwords}" | cut -d ',' -f $j)
  sudo echo "service: $service password: $password" >> /tmp/my_output.txt
done
```